# How to use block from different theme in magento?

Tags: layout, blocks, theme, custom

Is it possible to use a block from a different theme from the back-end?

I am using a customized theme without a layered navigation in for the catalog pages (category). So could I just get the layered navigation from the rwd theme via the "category"-- "custom design" tab. For example by calling the left block from rwd theme via the "Custom Layout Update"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to copy the XML from the RWD theme into your theme, and if the RWD theme is not part of your fallback structure you'll need to copy over the templates to.